# Qual o real significado de se utilizar ε-transições na NFA?

Tags: autômatos

Bom, eu ainda não compreendo a lógica de se utilizar ε-transições na NFA, qual o real significado? Pular de estado sem efetuar uma leitura?

Por exemplo, dada a regex:

```
a*
```

1. **NFA:**

   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2. **DFA:**

   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É alguma prova? Poderia ao menos passar o link do livro-texto... Ou [o tópico específico na Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_de_estados_finitos_n%C3%A3o_determin%C3%ADstica)... Em geral os problemas de automatos finitos ficam mais simples, e mais próximos do dia-a-dia de outro programador, quando traduzimos para expressões regulares.

Comment: Não, é estudo mesmo. No wikipédia encontra algumas informações. Sim, mas ainda não chego ao conceito de haverem tantas ε-transições na NFA acima.

Comment: Sugiro explicar melhor, traduzir para o ingles, e postar em http://math.stackexchange.com/ onde dominam a coisa.

Comment: Farei isso, obrigado, Peter.

Comment: Ah, eu acho que a tag ficaria melhor se fosse [tag:autômatos]: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1728/sobre-a-tag-aut%C3%B4mato

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A resposta do Anthony está perfeita, mas eu já estava escrevendo então vou postar porque pode ser de ajuda complementar.

Os dois autômatos (1) e (2) são equivalentes. A diferença bem explicada pelo Anthony é que as transições Epsilon (ou Lambda) permitem a mudança de estados sem consumir caracteres, funcionando quase como se o autômato mudasse de estado "sozinho" (o "não determinístico" no nome vem justamente do fato de que as mudanças podem ocorrer arbitráriamente, e não apenas para um único estado bem definido para cada símbolo, como nos AFD).

Assim:

1. a expressão regular `a*` deve aceitar apenas uma entrada vazia (nenhum símbolo) ou uma entrada com um ou mais símbolos `a` (por exemplo, `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, ...).
2. no caso do AFD (2), ambos os estados são de aceitação. Então, se o autômato receber uma entrada vazia, ele encerra aceitando-a porque estará no estado 0 (que é o inicial); senão, ao ler o primeiro símbolo `a`, muda para o estado 1, de onde não sai mais enquanto ler símbolos `a` da entrada, eventualmente terminando e aceitando-a ao acaber de ler tudo.
3. no caso do AFN-ε (1), apenas o estado 3 é de aceitação - sendo que o estado 0 é o inicial. Se a entrada for vazia, pode-se entender que *eventualmente* (em um momento arbitrário) o estado do autômato será alterado de 0 para 3 porque há uma transição-epsilon ligando esses dois estados. E nesse caso, ele aceitará a entrada vazia. Porém, o autômato pode também mudar para o estado 1 de forma arbitrária, de onde precisará ler ao menos um símbolo `a` para seguir para o estado 2 (nessa transição particular, de forma determinística), de onde pode voltar ao estado 1 ou seguir para o estado 3 também de forma não determinística. Assim, ele só aceitará a entrada quando ela for vazia, sendo que ele passou diretamente do estado 0 para o estado 3; ou quando a entrada não for vazia, sendo que ele passou do estado 0 para o estado 1, do estado 1 para o estado 2 *ao menos uma vez* (podendo circular entre os estados 2, 1 e 2 novamente para cada novo símbolo lido), e finalmente do estado 2 ao estado 3.

Note que esses autômatos são apenas modelos conceituais de máquinas computacionais processadoras de uma entrada simbólica, e a ideia de usar um AFN-ε é porque certos problemas são mais facilmente descritos (usando menos estados também) dessa forma. Mas como sempre é possível converter um AFN-ε em um AFD (há provas matemáticas desse fato), qualquer propriedade testada em um é válida para o outro.

Note também que os seus exemplos assumem que o alfabeto Σ contém apenas o símbolo `a`. Se a entrada pudesse também ter o símbolo `b` (por exemplo, `aaaabbab`), o próprio AFD não estaria correto por não ter transição(ões) para o símbolo `b`.

Comment: Dá para comparar um AFD com uma macro-função?

Comment: @Patrick O que você quer dizer exatamente com "macro-função"? Um programa em qualquer linguagem?

Comment: Muito obrigado, Luiz Vieira, sua resposta é mais esclarecedora.

Comment: @LuizVieira, sim.

Comment: @Patrick Autômatos são máquinas abstratas que resolvem problems computacionais, então a resposta é sim. Mas os AFDs e o AFNs têm limitações importantes relacionadas à capacidade de memória (eles só têm os estados). Há outras opções mais poderosas, como os autômatos com pilha (que podem "empilhar" símbolos lidos pra relembrá-los depois) e as [Máquinas de Turin](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_de_Turing) que podem fazer "saltos" pra frente ou pra trás na fila/fita de entrada. Esse último provê uma definição matemática formal de um algorítmo, sendo bem *mais próximo* de uma função real.

Comment: @Patrick Olha só, dá até pra "brincar" com uma Máquina de Turing no Google Doodles. :) http://www.google.com/doodles/alan-turings-100th-birthday

Comment: Mas essa maquina não tem AFN-Epsilon, né?

Comment: @Patrick Não, porque ela não precisa. :)

Answer (score 5):

Exatamente. [Transições Epsilon](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aut%C3%B4mato_finito_n%C3%A3o_determin%C3%ADstico_com_transi%C3%A7%C3%B5es_%CE%B5) permitem a mudança de estado sem consumir caracteres da cadeia de entrada. Essa característica aliada a possibilidade de mudar para mais do que um estado ao mesmo tempo caracterizam autômatos finitos não determinísticos (na verdade uma variação dos AFNDs conforme artigo da Wikipedia).

Comment: Muito obrigado, Anthony, problema resolvido.